reviewing low quality Posts: Incorrect == Low quality?
Context here is when reviewing posts in the “Low Quality Posts” queue.
this is an obviously honest attempt to answer the question, though it is 100% incorrect.

Looks OK: This is an honest attempt at answering the question and is not low quality.
Edit Improve and correct problems with this post yourself.
Delete This post cannot be fixed and should be deleted.

Is there an objectively correct reviewing outcome considering the above choices?
Normally, when editing, the principle we try to adhere to is, "don't change the OP's original intent."
if there are enough down votes on the question, I think it will be auto deleted in time. As a result, I am tempted to vote for deletion because I don't think it can be fixed.
I guess I'm asking if "correctness" is a dimension we should be considering when doing reviews for "low quality"?

My opinion, for what it is worth, is that if there is a minor error, go ahead and correct it, perhaps adding a comment. The person did their best and perhaps misstated something or, possibly, just has something wrong.
However, if major edits are required, it feels much more appropriate to just write an answer rather than attempt to rewrite someone else's. After all, the voting system takes care of indicating the overall "correctness" or "usefulness" of a question and an answer.

thanks David! Always appreciate your perspective. What are your thoughts on which is the appropriate item to selects in the “low quality“ review queue? “Looks ok”?

Mm... Good question. Let me think on that and let's see if there are any other participants.

Incorrect answers should be downvoted, IMHO. This is all that I can think of right now.
